# Using seperation of variables to solve a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Use separation of variables to find product solutions for the given PDE
>   $$ y u_{xy} + u = 0$$

Let $u(x,y) = X(x)T(y)$, then this PDE yields
$$y X'(x)T'(y) + X(x) T(y) = 0$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the equation $y \, u_{x y} + u = 0$ the proposer has provided $u(x,y) = f(x) g(y)$ for which
\begin{align}
y \, f' \, g + f \, g &= 0 \\
\frac{f'}{f} \, \frac{y g'}{g} &= -1. 
\end{align}
Now, in order to separate the variables constants need to be chosen such that the product is equal to $-1$, say $ -\lambda \cdot (1/\lambda)$, or
$$ \frac{f'}{f} \, \frac{y g'}{g} = - \lambda \cdot \frac{1}{\lambda}  = -1$$
leading to
\begin{align}
f' + \lambda \, f &= 0 \\
y \, g' - \frac{1}{\lambda} \, g &= 0.
\end{align}
The solutions of these equations are
\begin{align}
f(x) &=  c_{0} \, e^{-\lambda \, x} \\
g(y) &= c_{1} \, y^{\frac{1}{\lambda}}.
\end{align}
In terms of $u(x,y)$ it is seen that
$$u(x,y) = c_{2} \, e^{-\lambda \, x} \, y^{\frac{1}{\lambda}}.$$